# Regexp in ruby 1.8.7 that will detect a 4-byte Unicode character

Tags: ruby, regex, astral-plane

Can anyone tell me how I would write a ruby regexp in ruby 1.8.7 to detect the presence of a 4-byte unicode character (specifically the emoji)? I am trying to handle the fact that mysql [does not, by default](http://mzsanford.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/mysql-and-unicode/), allow you to store 4-byte emoji unicode characters, now in use by iOS 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the fix given in the article?

Comment: I have so many rows in my table, that an alter table would bring my site to a crashing halt for days. Unfortunately, not an option for us.

Comment: What about adding a new column instead, and running partial updates?

Comment: Any alter table I run locks the table for a long time, even adding a new column.

Comment: Can't you do that during downtime (eg: nights, weekends)

Comment: I know you want a direct answer, but just a note that long migrations should be run in isolation (clone of the DB/table) and then merged back when complete. It's not a simple process, since you need to perform a secondary lesser migration on the delta (i.e. the data that changed since you took a snapshot to work on in isolation), but it's considerably less intrusive to your users. I don't have a link... it's just something that we do ad-hoc, depending on the migration.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, the world is not flat.

Comment: Yes, I've dealt with large data migrations, and unfortunately, supporting emoji is simply not worth the engineering investment for us at this time. Hence, I need to detect these strings, and either strip them or convert them into something storable in mysql.

Comment: FWIW while I still would like to know if there is such a regexp, I have solved this problem by detecting if the string length saved in mysql != the string length I attempted to save. If so, I base64 encode the string with a sentinel value at the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to match the first two bytes of the four bytes that represent emoji. This is being run in ruby 1.8.7.

```
str.match(/\360\237/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Altering the table might be feasible using a non-blocking online approach, e.g. Maatkit's online-schema-change: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html

From the docs:

> In brief, this tool works by creating a temporary table which is a
>   copy of the original table (the one being altered). (The temporary
>   table is not created like CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE; we call it temporary
>   because it ultimately replaces the original table.) The temporary
>   table is altered, then triggers are defined on the original table to
>   capture changes made on it and apply them to the temporary table. This
>   keeps the two tables in sync. Then all rows are copied from the
>   original table to the temporary table; this part can take awhile. When
>   done copying rows, the two tables are swapped by using RENAME TABLE.
>   At this point there are two copies of the table: the old table which
>   used to be the original table, and the new table which used to be the
>   temporary table but now has the same name as the original table. If
>   --drop-old-table is specified, then the old table is dropped.