# To emoji or not to emoji?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I finally found a way to overcome issue with emojis in user inputs in my Rails 4 app. It was causing 'incorrect string value' errors.

The solution was to set utf8mb4 (using MySQL) not only in DB encoding*collation but also in database.yml.

So now it works. But the problem is that rendering is not consistent across the browsers as always :) And it feels like I have no control over user inputs anymore.

Is there an easy way to strip 4-byte characters, or possible just emojis from the user's input before saving the records and storing them in DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the attribute setters in your models to do whatever you want to the value before it's stored. Then, borrowing the regex from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774853/regexp-in-ruby-1-8-7-that-will-detect-a-4-byte-unicode-character) (looks Greek to me!), try:

```
# Do this for each attribute in your model:
def my_attr=(value)
  value = value.to_s.gsub(/\360\237/, '')
  super(value.presence)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I found one more solution for Emoji here: https://dev.firmafon.dk/blog/quick-no-hack-emoji-support-with-mysql-rails/

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :comment
end
```